# adj + as + pronoun + to be verb + verb can anyone explain?

Tags: grammar

I see an example in 504 essential words that I've never seen before.

the sentence structure is little bit strange for me.

Can anyone explain the definition and meaning

"Unaccustomed as he was to exercise,..."

And what is the difference with:

"he was unaccustomed to exercise"

Comment: The first is an incomplete sentence. The reader expects it to continue with something like "... he struggled to run across the park." The second sentence is complete.

Comment: "He was unaccustomed to exercise" is a simple statement that stands by itself.  "Unaccustomed as was" sets up a contrast or cause & effect.

Comment: It's sorta "interesting" that this *specific* example (and most syntactically similar alternatives?) is equally suitable for carrying the sense of either "contrast" or "explanation" (***even though*** he didn't exercise, he still completed the course, OR ***because*** he didn't exercise, he *couldn't* complete the course). But it's still basically an English Language Learners question.

Comment: Welcome! You can get better answers if you provide more of the sentence (if there is more), and explain more about what is confusing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clause you quoted works all together as one piece to be able to modify something else. It might be used in a sentence like:

> **Unaccustomed as he was to exercise,** he got tired quickly.

This seems confusing because it's a longer clause, but we can use shorter modifiers the same way:

> Tired, he fell asleep.

"Tired" modifies "he."

> Tired as he was, he couldn't fall asleep.
> Tired as he was, he fell asleep quickly.

In these, "tired as he was" means "as tired as he was," and is used to make two opposite points. The first means "Even though he was tired, he couldn't fall asleep," and the second means "Since he was so tired, he fell asleep quickly."

Answer (score 0):

> [*Unaccustomed as he was to exercise*]*, he was unable to complete the course*

Fronting the adjective "unaccustomed" in the bracketed phrase draws attention to the fact that he was not used to exercising. The adjective phrase is interpreted as giving the reason that he was unable to complete the course; compare the non-fronted word order in "Because he was unaccustomed to exercise, he was unable to complete the course", where the "because" expression is a reason adjunct.

Grammatically, the adjectival phrase *unaccustomed as he was to exercise* is a type of supplement (appendage) called a **predicative adjunct**, a loosely attached element located here at the beginning of the clause. It's predicative because it's related to a predicand, i.e. the subject "he", and it's an adjunct because it's an element in clause structure.